# How can I get a React component with prop types from a nested function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I want to get a component with its prop types, but Typescript cannot infer them if I return the component from a nested function.

I've tried to return the component from an unnested function, and it works, but not from a nested one

I expect to get the `ComponentType<ICompProps>` from getComponentFromNestedFunction

click the following link to see the full: [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hooks-dm3lo)

```
interface ICompProps {
    pass?: string;
    user?: string;
}

function getComponentFromNestedFunction<Props>(
    func: () => void
): (Comp: ComponentType<Props>) => ComponentType<Props> {
    return Comp => Comp;
}

function getComponent<Props>(
    Comp: ComponentType<Props>
): ComponentType<Props> {
    return Comp;
}

const Comp: ComponentType<ICompProps> = p => {
    return <div>{p.user}</div>;
};

// How can I change the code so I can  get the prop types like in ComponentWithPropTypes?
const ComponentWithoutPropTypes = getComponentFromNestedFunction(() => ({
    user: "user"
}))(Comp);

// hover (in a code editor) ComponentWithPropTypes and see the prop types: const ComponentWithPropTypes: React.ComponentType<ICompProps>
const ComponentWithPropTypes = getComponent(Comp);

}
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to have a function that passes the props you enter in the function by argument to the component,no?

Comment: Nope. I want the prop types of the outer function to be inferred from the inner function, where they are passed